# Loading TFS assembly error

Tags: tfs

I am trying to execute tfs commands using powershell scripts and getting the following issue

Unable to find type [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationServerFactory]: make sure that the assembly containing this type is loaded.

What needs to be done?

Thanks
Jai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my box the assembly holding that type is here:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll.

Probably powershell is not probing in that directory.

Try copying the assembly to the folder where your popwershell script is.