# Changing NotificationJobLogLevel setting in the TFS registry using PowerShell

Tags: logging, powershell

I am trying to enable email alert notifications for TFS 2012.

I was looking into the answer in [TFS 2012 Team Alerts not sending emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14566315/tfs-2012-team-alerts-not-sending-emails/14732225#14732225) which gives a quite detailed description on how to enable email notification. After all the setup it still doesn't work and mails are still not sended.

therefore i wanted to check the TFS job history loggings and found this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/granth/archive/2009/10/28/tfs2010-diagnosing-email-and-soap-subscription-failures.aspx

as expected it gives me a message that some messages were not send and some errors occured:

```
There were errors or warnings during notification delivery.    
0/6 emails delivered.  
0/0 soap notifications delivered.   
6 errors.  0 warnings.    
Set /Service/Integration/Settings/NotificationJobLogLevel in the TF registry to 2 to see errors and warnings.
```

So i tried to change the NotificationJobLogLevel to 2 just as suggested and to see the full log and stack trace.

This article gives a very detailed step by step instruction on how to do this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/granth/archive/2009/10/28/tfs2010-diagnosing-email-and-soap-subscription-failures.aspx and how to change the setting by using powershell.

But running the following part of the script doesn't work:

```
# Load client OM assembly. 
[Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a");
```

and results in the following error:

[image]

Again i was looking into that issue and found a similar issue here: [Loading TFS assembly error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920110/loading-tfs-assembly-error)

There he suggests to copy the .dll into the same folder as the executed powershell script, which i did. but again, the script couldn't find the .dll file.

If you guys have any hints or help for me on where i am doing something wrong, i would really appreciate it.

**EDIT:** Also if there is another possiblity to change the TFS registry entry (maybe directly by using regedit?) i would be happy if you guys let me know. I was looking for that registry entry, but didn't find it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to load version `11.0` not `10.0` of the Team Foundation Client assembly:

`[Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a");`

I had to do this on our server the other day.